# gitlab: PAM authentication issues

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using gitlab for a departmental git server for my university. We have an existing user base maintained by a different part of the organization. My IT admin would rather use PAM than straight LDAP to authenticate.

I got PAM working on Ubuntu 12.04, by replacing the unix_chkpwd binary. Right now it is through Omniauth. The logs show that it authenticates. I get a routing error after successful sign in.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/auth/pam/callback"):
```

I am not sure how to go about fixing this.

I would like devise to use PAM directly since all my users will be only through PAM, since the will have to have a university account. I am using the folowing gem https://github.com/jwilson511/devise_pam_authenticatable . I have it setup, but it does not seem to be attempting to login through PAM.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I have PAM configured right. The issue is with the routing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The gem needed to be setup to have a name option that gitlab will parse out correctly.

The gem also needed to be set to add an email field to the info hash, such that a user will be created on first login.

I will do some code cleanup and make a pull request.

Comment: I'm runnin' a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938781/gitlab-and-omniauth-pam-authentication
We hope to get this https://github.com/raphendyr/gitlabhq/tree/6-3-pam into gitlab

Answer (score 0):

you can use the omniauth providers,

for details on the omniauth providers see https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Using-Custom-Omniauth-Providers

for an pam omniauth provider see https://github.com/nickcharlton/omniauth-pam

Comment: I am testing it with Omniauth as of now. The routing error is from using Omniauth.

Comment: I may not have the config right for Omniauth.
I have the gem installed and added to the gitlab.yml the provider of
    - { name: 'PAM' }